# How can I check if a given data table has been rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a function that selects all checkboxes (`selecionarTodos()`) on all pages of a table (`#tbTarefas`). However, I want to use the same method to select all checkboxes in other tables, which have the same structure, only with different `id`.

I would like to check if a certain table is rendered at that moment on screen. Something like that.

**Before**

```js
function selecionarTodos(source) {
        const tabela = $("#tbTarefas").DataTable();
        let celulasCheckbox = tabela.column(0).nodes();

        for (let i = 0; i < celulasCheckbox.length; i++) {
            let checkbox = celulasCheckbox[i].querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

            checkbox.checked = source.checked;
        }
    }
```

**After** (*Initial thinking*)

```js
function selecionarTodos(source) {
        const tabelaTarefas = $("#tbTarefas").DataTable();
        const tabelaAtendimento = $("#tbPendentes").DataTable();

        if (tabelaTarefas) {
            let CheckboxTarefasTd = tabelaTarefas.column(0).nodes();

            for (let i = 0; i < CheckboxTarefasTd.length; i++) {
                let checkbox = CheckboxTarefasTd[i].querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

                checkbox.checked = source.checked;
            }
        }
        else if (tabelaAtendimento) {
            let CheckboxAtendimentoTd = tabelaAtendimento.column(0).nodes();

            for (let i = 0; i < CheckboxAtendimentoTd.length; i++) {
                let checkbox = CheckboxAtendimentoTd[i].querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

                checkbox.checked = source.checked;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: In case it is relevant: You can select multiple tables at once, using something like `const allMyTables= $(".myTableClass").DataTable();`. This example uses a class name as the selector, not an ID. See [the API documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/) for details.  See also [Multiple Tables](https://datatables.net/manual/api#Multiple-tables).

Comment: @andrewjames I am grateful for the suggestion, but in this case, I need to select each table individually even though each one involves a business rule of the application. In this case, I don't know if I would decide to check if that table was rendered on each page, as there are pages that have more than one table.

Answer (score 2):

Datatables has a callback for once initialization has been completed.

```
$('#tbTarefas').on( 'init.dt', function () { 

}
```

Or on each redraw use "draw.dt"

Comment: oops, slight mix up! I've updated the answer.